# How to append new column without creating an array in advance?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I want to add a new column one by one, and I simplified my code:

```
import numpy as np
score = [[99], [99]]
for j in range (5):
    temp = []
    for i in range (2):
        temp.append(i)
    temp = np.array(temp)
    score = np.c_[score, temp.T]
score = np.delete(score, obj=0, axis=1)
print(score)
```

I want to add a new column `[1, 2].T` at each step, so that the array looks like this:

```
[1] -> [1, 1] -> ...
[2]    [2, 2]
```

However, I have to create the first column `[[99], [99]]` and delete it in the end. Is there some better method can skip this step?

Comment: Do another layer of list append.  At the end make the 2d array and transpose if necessary.

Comment: For one thing, you can start with `score = np.empty((2, 0)` instead of `[[99], [99]]`. For another, lists and deques are much better at appending than numpy arrays. Your loop is making me cry inside a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your literal question, you can create empty lists or arrays as placeholders:

```
score = [[], []]
score = np.empty((2, 0))
score = np.array([[], []])
...
```

Numpy arrays are not a good tool for appending. Make an array once the data is at a fixed size. Assuming that you don't know how many columns you will have, something like this is OK:

```
score = [[], []]
for j in range(5):
    for i, row in zip(range(2), score):
        row.append(i)
score = np.array(score)
```

Or better yet:

```
score = []
for j in range(5):
    score.append(list(range(2)))
score = np.array(score).T
```

If you want a C-contiguous result, replace the last line with

```
score = np.array(score, order='F').T
```